# Using Ivy/Maven for C++ binary dependancy management in Visual C++ environment

Tags: visual-c++, maven, ivy, dependency-management

I am looking to provide a better way of managing the distribution and storage of binary dependencies for a large VC++ project.

Currently we have the situation where externally and internal built libraries are stored within the the source control repository resulting in the .cpp and .h files forming less than 3% of the space that is retrieved. This makes the process of creating a branch slow, and prevents sensible migration to a DVCS.

I don't want to change the main method of building through MS visual studio solutions, but I am willing to add an additional step to fetch/setup all the binary dependencies.

This is currently achieved for some libraries using are existing Source Control, by mounting different repositories containing the built files. This could be one approach (which I don't favour).

Has anybody got experience of using Ivy or Maven in a VC++ environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [maven-nar-plugin](http://duns.github.com/maven-nar-plugin/) might be solution for you.

Comment: I was aware of maven-nar-plugin, which as Ivy likes to use maven2 repositories, seems the best fit. But I still have not found how to build maven-nar repositories from pre built third party artifacts (ie the headers/libs/binaries)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) is a alternative solution for you.

Documentation is available [here](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or for Visual Studio [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=msvc-160)